# Why do my std::atomic::compare_exchange_weak implemented stack crash some time?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, thread-safety

I'm trying to write a simple thread safe stack using c++11 atomic class.
These are what I've come so far.

```
    void pushNode(Node* node) {
//
//      node->_next = _head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
//      while(!_head.compare_exchange_weak(node->_next, node));
//
// http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange
// Note: the above use is not thread-safe in at least
// GCC prior to 4.8.3 (bug 60272), clang prior to 2014-05-05 (bug 18899)
// MSVC prior to 2014-03-17 (bug 819819). The following is a workaround:
        Node* head = _head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        do {
            node->_next = head;
        } while(!_head.compare_exchange_weak(head, node,
                            std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed));
    }

    Node* popNode() {
        Node* head;
        Node* expected = _head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        do {
            head = expected;
        } while(head && !_head.compare_exchange_weak(expected, head->_next,
                            std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed));
        if(head)
            head->_next = nullptr;
        return head;
    }

    void pop() {
        delete popNode();
    }

private:
    std::atomic<Node*> _head;
```

I also write a testcase to find out how solid this stack is under certain conditions (3 threads, each commits a million times of push and pop operations randomly). And the answer is not much.

The testcase crashes some time, raising an access violation exception reading 0xbaadf00d 0xfeeefeee 0xcdcdcdcd or some other invalid memory address.

After a few days googling, the only thing I've found could possibly cause this problem is [Is std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak thread-unsafe by design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21879331/is-stdatomic-compare-exchange-weak-thread-unsafe-by-design). And as commented in the code, I find a workround here, [std::atomic::compare_exchange_weak](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange). Dont know whether the ms guy get rid of this buggy implementations in my compiler (MSVC 2015 community) or not, I just apply the workround patch.

But no magic appears, the testcase crashes as usual.

Is std::atomic::compare_exchange_weak still bugly implemented, or I just did something stupid?

Comment: pop is a lot more complex than push, check out Concurrency in Action for several approaches.

Comment: @Cubbi, thanks to your reply and the question you've asked which inspires me. But I really need now is an answer telling me what's wrong here, not a name of book I don't have. :)

Comment: If two threads call `pop()` at about the same time, then one could try to access `head->_next` after the head node has already been deleted. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_pointer

Comment: @Igor, GJ. You're showing me the right direction. Accessing deleted node itself will not raise a reading 0xfeeefeee address exception, but the ABA problem will. Thought of it before, but I didn't think that may be the case, cause I never reuse any Node, they're popped and deleted. Unless deleted Node got allocated again!  Please post an answer and I'll accept it.