# what atomicity does compare_exchange_weak provide?

Tags: c++, compare-and-swap

quote from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange

> bool compare_exchange_weak( T& expected, T desired,
> std::memory_order success,
> std::memory_order failure ) noexcept;

> Atomically compares the object representation (until C++20)value representation (since C++20) of *this with that of expected, and if those are bitwise-equal, replaces the former with desired (performs read-modify-write operation). Otherwise, loads the actual value stored in *this into expected (performs load operation).

I'm having a hard time understanding the word *Atomically* mentioned above. Because `expected` and `desired` are all of type T, so read & write operation on these values are not atomic, if underlying atomic value and `expected` are not equal, Is the operation of loading `*this` to `expected` also atomic? or does *Atomically* only applies to operation related to underlying atomic value?

Comment: "Atomically" in the sense that no other operation was performed on the data in the meantime. If another thread does something to the variable then the operation will happen either before or after.

Comment: Are you trying to say that neither reading nor writing are atomic for some specific type `T` you have in mind? Or that a combined read+write operation can't be atomic? Please clarify that last paragraph, it's hard to tell what specifically you're confused about.

Comment: @Useless I'm asking that if *this is not equal to expected value, is the operation of comparing *this with expected and loading *this into expected uninterruptible?

Comment: @Useless Is there a possibility that one thread is in compare_exchange_weak function and *this is not equal to expected, so it need load *this into expected, and another thread is also writing to expected, thus there is a data race?

Comment: OK, now I understand your question. When you say _of type `T`_, the significant observation is that the the parameters are _not_ of type `atomic<T>`. It's very confusingly phrased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because `expected` and `desired` are all of type T, so read & write operation on these values are not atomic

That's true. The load of `expected` (and the store, if it happens) is not an atomic operation. Therefore, if this call to `compare_exchange_weak` is potentially concurrent with any other operation that accesses `expected`, the program has a race condition (unless both operations are only reads). The load of `desired` is also not an atomic operation, although this doesn't matter because it's a local variable in the `compare_exchange_weak` function (no other thread can see it).

However, the operation on `*this` is atomic. This means that it will not race with any other potentially concurrent atomic operation on `*this`; if there are two potentially concurrent atomic operations on `*this`, the behaviour will be as if one thread or the other "gets there first", without causing any undefined behaviour. Furthermore, it will be either an atomic read-modify-write operation (on success) or an atomic load operation (on failure). An atomic read-modify-write operation has the additional constraint that the entry that it creates in the atomic variable's modification order immediately follows the entry from which the read took its value (no other modifications can "intervene").

Answer (score 1):

Naively, the

> compares the [representation] of `*this` with that of expected

and

> replaces the former with desired

could be two separate operations that happen sequentially. One could imagine that it is possible that another thread writes a value after *compares* but before *replaces* into `*this` so that the second operation, *replaces*, overwrites the value that was just written by the other thread, which is now lost.

*Atomically* means that this cannot happen, i.e., that the two operations are actually only one uninterruptible operation.

Comment: if *this is not equal to expected value, is the operation of comparing *this with expected and loading *this into expected also uninterruptible?

Comment: @codesavesworld Yes, of course.

Comment: but writing to expected, which is a non-atomic value is not atomic operation. Then how can 
 compare_exchange_weak(strong) be lock-free?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21879331/is-stdatomic-compare-exchange-weak-thread-unsafe-by-design check the last paragraph of top-voted answer, it suggests that write *this to expected is not atomic

Comment: @codesavesworld Good catch! In the case where `expected` must be written to, only the part that *reads* from `*this` falls into the requirement to be *atomic*. There never is a need that the subsequent write to `expected` be atomic as it is not visible to other threads anyway.