# Does std::atomic<struct> makes all member also atomic?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Lets say we have  a structure as below-

```
struct test
{
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

I make a atomic variable of this structure and try to update a and b. Will these operations be atomic? What does it mean to make a structure/class atomic?

```
std::atomic<test> t;
t.a = 10;   // is this an atomic operation?
t.b = 20;   // is this an atomic operation?
// I understand a and b are not atomic in themselves but I am confused     
// as to when you say struct temp is atomic what does it mean?
// does it mean the t instance's this pointer is atomic?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use std::atomic<> effectively for non-primitive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885617/how-to-use-stdatomic-effectively-for-non-primitive-types)

Comment: short answer: no, as the documentation explains, it makes getting and setting copies of the entire struct atomic, but not direct access to its members.

Comment: Pointless because `t.a` is invalid. `a` is a member of `test`, not `atomic<test>`

Comment: @LWimsey (I still dream of `operator.`)

Answer (score 5):

Your are wrapping a POD in an `atomic` type. On the atomic object `t`, only atomic operations can be performed, such as `load()`, `store()` and `compare_exchange_weak()`.
Those operations apply to the entire POD (not a part of it) and are indivisible; i.e. they happen uninterrupted, or they don't happen at all.

If you want to atomically change member `a`, that is only possible while updating the entire `t` object, but since you don't want to modify member `b`,
you'll need a CAS (compare-and-swap) operation:

```
std::atomic<test> t;

test expected = t.load();
test desired;

do {
    desired = expected;
    desired.a = 10;

} while(!t.compare_exchange_weak(expected, desired));
```

If `t` is modified by another thread of execution between `load()` and `compare_exchange_weak()`, the latter will update `expected` (an lvalue) with the new value of `t` and return 0.
You then set `desired` again based on the updated `expected` and try again.

With a plain `store()` instead of a CAS, an update made by another thread could be overwritten (i.e. lost).